# Get the full type signature using ghc-mod (M-x ghc-show-type)

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack, ghc-mod

Consider `Foo.hs`:

```hs
module Foo where

foo :: Num t => t
foo = 3
```

running `ghc-mod -type` on it like this only gives me the type `t` for the signature of `foo`, even though the declaration already has the full type signature attached to it:

```
$ ghc-mod type src/Foo.hs 4 1
4 1 4 8 "t"
```

This becomes highly limiting when wanting to use `ghc-mod` for adding a type to a declaration without one.

Is there a way to get the full type from `ghc-mod`?

Alternatively, what are the tools one can use in place of `ghc-mod` to achieve this? Can these tools be used alongside with `ghc-mod`, (for example in Emacs)?

---

**EDIT:** `stack-ide` too reports the type to be just `t` not the full `Num t => t`:

```
[nil] -> {"tag":"RequestGetExpTypes","contents":{"spanFilePath":"src\/Foo.hs","spanFromLine":4,"spanFromColumn":1,"spanToLine":4,"spanToColumn":4}}
 <- {"tag":"ResponseGetExpTypes","contents":[["t",{"spanFromLine":4,"spanFilePath":"src/Foo.hs","spanToColumn":4,"spanFromColumn":1,"spanToLine":4}]]}
```